# How to use multiple prefixes in anything-but clause in AWS eventbridge eventpattern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless, aws-event-bridge, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I have a situation where I need to filter out certain events using eventpatterns in eventbridge.
I want to run the rule for all events except those where username starts with abc or xyz.
I have tried below 2 syntax but none worked :

```
"userIdentity": {
      "sessionContext": {
        "sessionIssuer": {
          "userName": [
            {
              "anything-but": {
                "prefix": [
                  "abc-",
                  "xyz-"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }

"userIdentity": {
      "sessionContext": {
        "sessionIssuer": {
          "userName": [
            {
              "anything-but": [{
                "prefix": "abc-",
                "prefix": "xyz-"
              }]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Getting following error on saving the rule :
"*Event pattern is not valid. Reason: Inside anything but list, start|null|boolean is not supported.*"

Am I missing something in the syntax or if this is a limitation then is there any alternative to this problem?

Comment: as far as the documentation concerned [Content-based Filtering with Event Patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html) you can't provide multiple `prefixes`

Comment: so is there any alternate way of achieving this(apart from having multiple rules) ?

Comment: either split up rules or try not to match based on the prefix

Answer (score 7):

You can use prefix within an array in event pattern. Here is an example pattern:

```
{
      "detail": {
        "alarmName": [{
            "prefix": "DemoApp1"
          },
          {
            "prefix": "DemoApp2"
          }
        ],
        "state": {
          "value": [
            "ALARM"
          ]
        },
        "previousState": {
          "value": [
            "OK"
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

This event will match alarm that has name starting with either *DemoApp1* or *DemoApp2*

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: user @samtoddler is sort of correct.

Prefix matches only work on values as called out in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html#filtering-prefix-matching. They do not work with arrays. You can file a feature request with AWS support but if you'd like to unblock yourself; you it's probably best to either control the prefixes you have for userName (guessing this is something IAM related and in your control).

If that's not possible; consider filtering as much as you can via other properties before sending over to a compute (probably lambda) to performing additional filtering.