# aws cloudwatch event rule on multiple s3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

how to create cloudwatch event rule which will be triggered on creation of multiple s3 files. Shall we use multiple key prefix in event pattern?

```
{
  "detail": {
    "eventName": [
      "PutObject"
    ],
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": [
        "bucket name here"
      ],
      "key": [
        {
          "prefix": "prefix1 here/filename1.txt"
        },
        {
          "prefix": "prefix2 here/filename2.txt"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I do not think its possible. You need a fully custom solution for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple prefixes in anything-but clause in AWS eventbridge eventpattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993743/how-to-use-multiple-prefixes-in-anything-but-clause-in-aws-eventbridge-eventpatt)